# Where can i find the "Application does not run in background" key

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I use the Xcode 4.2 (iOS5), where can i find the `Application does not run in background` to turn it to YES.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of your application's information is stored in its `Info.plist` file.

In your project, there is a file named `YourProjectName-Info.plist`.
Select that file, then use the menu `Editor` > `Add Item` and type `Application does not run in background`.

Comment: It is equivalent to UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend : YES